# kafka `consumer.poll` gets stuck when reaching the end of the topic

Tags: apache-kafka, observable, kafka-consumer-api

I wrote a simple client to read from a Kafka topic, which had worked well until I realized the consumer.poll will block and never return when it reaches the end of the topic.

Following is a sample of my code

```scala
    Observable
    .repeatEval(consumer.poll(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(100)))
    .timeoutOnSlowUpstreamOn(FiniteDuration(1000, MILLISECONDS), Observable.empty)
    .filter(_ ne null)
```

I was expecting when nothing could be consumed from the topic for 1 second, `timeOnSlowUpStreamOn` will convert the original source into an empty `Observable`. However because the `Scheduler` is blocked on `consumer.poll` when it reaches the end of the topic, the `timeout` never happens.

Looking at the thread dump, the program is stuck at:

```
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:689)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:409)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:510)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:271)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242)
```

I don't quite care whether this is by design or some sort of "bug". I am just wondering if there is a way to make `consumer.poll` return (normal way or through throwing exception): blocking a scheduler is the last thing I want to see in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize `KafkaConsumer` is not thread safe. More than 1 thread calling its methods at the same time would throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. After doing some proper synchronization, the problem gets resolved.